# Don't understand something from a book (PPP by Bjarne Stroustrup)

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

constexpr int not_a_reading = -7777;
constexpr int not_a_month = -1;

constexpr int implausible_min = -200;

constexpr int implausible_max = 200;

vector<string> month_tbl = { "january", "febuary", "march", "april","may","june","july","august",
"september","october","november","december" };

struct Day
{
    //made a day struct containing a day vec which has 24 elements(24 hours)
    //and each element contains the temperature at that hour.
    vector<int> hour = vector<int>(24, not_a_reading);
    
};
struct Month
{
    int month = not_a_month;
    vector<Day> day{ 32 };
    //throwing away day[0]
};
struct Year
{
    int year;
    vector<Month> month{ 12 };

};
struct Reading { //just for reading data.
    int day;
    int hour;
    double temperature;
};

int month_to_int(string m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < month_tbl.size(); i++)
    {
        if (month_tbl[i] == m) return i + 1;
    }
    return -1; //problem
}
bool is_valid(const Reading& r)
// a rough test
{
    if (r.day < 1 || 31 < r.day) return false;
    if (r.hour < 0 || 23 < r.hour) return false;
    if (r.temperature < implausible_min || implausible_max < r.temperature)
        return false;
    return true;
}
void end_of_loop(istream& ist, char term, const string& message)
{
    if (ist.fail()) { // use term as terminator and/or separator

        ist.clear();
        char ch;
        if (ist >> ch && ch == term) return; // all is fine
        throw runtime_error(message);
    }
}
//overloading insertion operator(>>)
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Reading& r)
// read a temperature reading from is into r
// format: ( 3 4 9.7 )
// check format, but don’t bother with data validity
{
    char ch1;
    if (is >> ch1 && ch1 != '(') { // could it be a Reading?
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit); //set stream to fail state
        return is;
    }
    char ch2;
    int d;
    int h;
    double t;
    is >> d >> h >> t >> ch2;
    if (!is || ch2 != ')') throw runtime_error("bad reading"); // messed-up reading
    r.day = d;
    r.hour = h;
    r.temperature = t;
    return is;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Month& m) 
// read a month from is into m
// format: { month feb . . . }
{
    char ch = 0;
    if (is >> ch && ch != '{') {
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit); // we failed to read a Month
        return is;
    }
    //we got a {

    string month_marker;
    string mm;
    is >> month_marker >> mm;
    if (!is || month_marker != "month") throw runtime_error("bad start of month");
    m.month = month_to_int(mm);
    int duplicates = 0;
    int invalids = 0;
    for (Reading r; is >> r; ) {
        if (is_valid(r)) {
            if (m.day[r.day].hour[r.hour] != not_a_reading)
                ++duplicates;
            m.day[r.day].hour[r.hour] = r.temperature;
        }
        else
            ++invalids;
    }
    if (invalids) throw runtime_error("invalid readings in month");
    if (duplicates) throw runtime_error("duplicate readings in month");
    end_of_loop(is, '}', "bad end of month");
    return is;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Year& y)
// read a year from is into y
// format: { year 1972 . . . }
{
    char ch;
    is >> ch;
    if (ch != '{') {
        is.unget();
        is.clear(ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    //awesome it was {

    string year_marker;
    int yy;
    is >> year_marker >> yy;
    if (!is || year_marker != "year") throw runtime_error("bad start of year");
    y.year = yy;
    while (true) {
        Month m; // get a clean m each time around
        if (!(is >> m)) break;

        y.month[m.month] = m;
    }
    end_of_loop(is, '}', "bad end of year");
    return is;
}


int main()
{
    Reading r;
    ifstream ist("justtext.txt");
    ist >> r;
    cout << r.day << '\n';
    cout << r.hour << '\n';
    cout << r.temperature << '\n';
}
```

> We would have preferred “boringly similar” to just “similar,” but
> there is a significant difference. Have a look at the read loop. Did
> you expect something like the following?

```
for (Month m; is >> m; )
 y.month[m.month] = m;
```

> You probably should have, because that’s the way we have written all
> the read loops so far. That’s actually what we first wrote, and it’s
> wrong. The problem is that operator>>(istream& is, Month& m) doesn’t
> assign a brand-new value to m; it simply adds data from Readings to m.
> Thus, the repeated is>>m would have kept adding to our one and only m.
> Oops! Each new month would have gotten all the readings from all
> previous months of that year. We need a brand-new, clean Month to read
> into each time we do is>>m. The easiest way to do that was to put the
> definition of m inside the loop so that it would be initialized each
> time around.

I just don't understand how what he's saying here is true? He says `is>>m` doesn't assign a brand new value to `m` but if I look at the overloaded operator for months it seems that it does?

When he says this he's talking about the code in the overloaded `>>` operator for year.

```
while(true) {
Month m; // get a clean m each time around
if(!(is >> m)) break;

y.month[m.month] = m;
}
```

I understand that the for loop just creates the `m` object once and keeps using that in the loop over and over just that same object but what I don't get is how it ADDS any data if we keep using the same object? The overloaded operator for month does not seem to ADD any data to me? It just SETS values I don't see how it's adding data anywhere can someone explain this to me? All I can see is that I do `is >> m` which yes it reading into the same value but it's not adding anything it's setting values then it sets `y.month[m.month]` equal to that object then just keeps doing this so next time it reads another month gives the m object new values and then again sets `y.month[m.month]` equal to month which now has different values? What am I missing?

Comment: The key is in `istream& operator>>(istream& is, Month& m) `. That function **modifies** `m` without resetting it.

Comment: And? Why does that matter? Of course I have to pass it by reference so it can actually give m a value but so what if it doesn't reset it? is >> or operator>>(is, m) reads some data into m gives it some values then sets y.month[m.month] equal to m. Then it keeps doing this so what data keeps getting added on here that's what I don't understand?

Comment: But in the offending code the same `Month` object is being recycled. So the mutations done by `m.day[r.day].hour[r.hour] = r.temperature;` from the previous loop iterations will still be in there. The problem comes from the code inside of `istream& operator>>(istream& is, Month& m)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler program showcasing the same issue:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Foo& f) {
  int v;
  is >> v;

  // even values go to x, odd values go to y
  if(v % 2 == 0) {
     f.x = v;
  }
  else {
    f.y = v;
  }

  return is;
}

int main() {
  for(Foo the_foo; std::cin >> the_foo;) {
      std::cout << "{" << the_foo.x << ", " << the_foo.y << "}\n";
  }
}
```

If I pass `1 2 3 4` to this program as `stdin`, I get the following output:

```
{0, 1}
{2, 1}
{2, 3}
{4, 3}
```

This is because `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Foo& f)` does not **set** `f`, it only **alters** it, so the members of `f` that are not touched by the operation will be left as-is. And since we only create a single `the_foo` object, and pass it over and over again to that function, mutations done by previous iterations of the loop end up affecting the value of `the_foo` during the next ones.

If we use this instead:

```
int main() {
  while(true) {
    Foo the_foo;
    if(!(is >> the_foo)) break;

    std::cout << "{" << the_foo.x << ", " << the_foo.y << "}\n";
  }
}
```

Then, with the same `1 2 3 4` input, the output becomes:

```
{0, 1}
{2, 0}
{0, 3}
{4, 0}
```

That's because every iteration of the loop starts from a fresh `the_foo`, with both fields initialized to 0.

You can play with this example on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6GExWqsdW)